# Jquery AJAX request body is empty. (Django REST inside Docker)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Loading a template, index.html, with JS that's inside the /static directory.

Javascript(app.js):

```
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.startTime = "123";
    obj.endTime = "456";
    console.log("fetchNext "+JSON.stringify(obj));
    var data1 = {"name":"John Doe"}

    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8000/api/time/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It's hitting the Django REST API, but body is empty.

```
class QueryTime(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = "false"
        jsonstr = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        # jsonstr is empty.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have installed CORS and tried whether it fixes or not, and had no luck. And I get these results.

```
web_1  | [07/Mar/2019 17:36:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 314
web_1  | [07/Mar/2019 17:36:52] "GET /static/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
web_1  | 
web_1  | [07/Mar/2019 17:36:52] "GET /api/time/?{%22startTime%22:%22123%22,%22endTime%22:%22456%22} HTTP/1.1" 200 7
```

Not sure what these status codes represent. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: `GET` requests don't have a body. The data is encoded in the query string of the URL (as you can see in your console) - you should use `request.GET` to access it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Amazing, that worked! Thanks for the help!! I changed the method to POST to hide the url, not sure why Postman behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

I see something strange your api so I work like this

```
class MODELAPI2(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
    serializer_class = MyModel_Serializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyModel_Filter
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    def get_queryset(self):

       param1 = self.request.query_params.get('param1')
       param2 = self.request.query_params.get('param2')
       argumentos = {}
        if param1 != '':
            argumentos['param1'] =param1
        if param1 != '':
            argumentos['param2'] = param2
       query = Mymodel.objects.filter(**argumentos)
       return query
```

and ajax . `method:"GET", data:{'param1':param1,'param2':param2}`